# jq: divide a decimal number but keep precision

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON data that looks like this:

```json
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "frame": 1,
      "timestamp": 0,
      "r": 130,
      "g": 105,
      "b": 99
    },
    {
      "frame": 2,
      "timestamp": 99.96299999999974,
      "r": 129,
      "g": 105,
      "b": 99
    },
...
}
```

I've tried running `jq '.entries[].timestamp = .entries[].timestamp/1000.0' data.json` but the outcome has lost precision on the values. I'm getting:

```json
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "frame": 1,
      "timestamp": 0,
      "r": 130,
      "g": 105,
      "b": 99
    },
    {
      "frame": 2,
      "timestamp": 0,
      "r": 129,
      "g": 105,
      "b": 99
    },
...
}
```

Have I missed something obvious here? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Your filter is incorrect, use `/=`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `jq` promises any particular amount of precision. It's probably implementation-specific, depending on the floating-point values of the underlying C libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't lose precision, you just created more results.

Use the update operator `|=` instead. In this case, you could even go with `/=`.

```
jq '.entries[].timestamp /= 1000.0' data.json
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/81PPFCdDIk)

Answer (score 1):

The two `[]` conspired to create n^2 entries.

```sh
jq '.entries[].timestamp = .entries[].timestamp/1000.0'   # BAD
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/lLDw6XAO2P)

---

Extract the common bits.

```sh
jq '.entries[] |= ( .timestamp = .timestamp/1000.0 )'   # Good
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/Dcvn3qfuu-)

---

Simplified:

```sh
jq '.entries[] |= ( .timestamp /= 1000.0 )'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/GG09nvQL7T)

---

Simplified:

```sh
jq '.entries[].timestamp /= 1000.0'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/81PPFCdDIk)

Comment: `//=` is the update variant of the alternative operator `//`, not of the division operator `/`.

Comment: Ack, typo. Fixed.